# How can i run Dart code on background in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, beacon, background-service

I want scan beacon devices on background and run my dart code for send data to my backend. How can i do that? I found background service documentation but i didn't find how can i run dart code on background.

Comment: Check it [out](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/background-processes#:~:text=In%20Flutter%2C%20you%20can%20execute%20Dart%20code%20in%20the%20background.)

Comment: @PratikButani i saw that but i want only listen my Beacon Scanner's dart code. As i understand this documentation built an service. Basicly i want run an dart code on background. Can you help me about this?